# NHibernate number format problem - where do I set the culture?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, formatting, numbers, culture

**LATER EDIT : It was me :( It was a non-nullable column left unfilled. Sorry to everyone I confused..**

I am having issues with an INSERT statement generated by NHibernate because it formats the decimal numbers using the regional settings. The generated statement goes something like :

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [TableName] (
    Column1, 
    Column2, 
    Column3, 
    Column4, 
    Column5, 
    Column6, 
    Column7, 
    Column8, 
    Column9, 
    Column10) 
VALUES (@p0, 
    @p1, 
    @p2, 
    @p3, 
    @p4, 
    @p5, 
    @p6, 
    @p7, 
    @p8, 
    @p9); 

select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',

N'@p0 float,@p1 float,@p2 float,@p3 float,@p4 int,@p5 datetime,@p6 nvarchar(69),@p7 int,@p8 int,@p9 int',
@p0=0,
@p1=0,
@p2=589186,74188329,           -- <-- here is my problem
@p3=320829,21535209997,        -- <-- here is my problem
@p4=6,
@p5='2009-05-10 17:00:00',
@p6=N'Some string value',
@p7=232323,
@p8=2,
@p9=1
```

As you can see there is a comma used as a decimal separator which screws up the parameters value list.

I have not found anywhere a way to set the culture used to format the numbers so the statement would get generated in a valid form.

I set the Thread.CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture to en-us right before the Save method call on the ISession but nothing happened.

What can be done? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But this list with formatted numbers is only for display purposes - the values being set as the parameters are set as floating point numbers. This shouldn't cause the INSERT to fail in any way.

Are you just *anticipating* a problem, or are you actually getting an error? If you are getting an error, what is it?

Comment: This query has been intercepted in SQL Server Profiler. It is the query actually sent.

Comment: Yes, but it is a parameterised query, and where the parameter values are being written out they are being formatted. But where they are set, they are set as native float values.

Comment: Well it's actually failing reporting exactly this issue.

Comment: I've switched my regional settings from Romanian to English (United States) and now it's ok, there are dots instead of commas and the statement doesn't fail anymore. How could I convince NHibernate to work on other regional settings? :((((((

Comment: OK - so can you post the details of the exception?

Comment: Post the code that generates the statements. I use NHiberante with comma locale and I didn't had to change anything.

Comment: I am so sorry, my mistake. It was a non-nullable column. I saw the INSERT fail, captured it with SQL Profiler and looked over the string. Seeing the commas there made me think they were the culprit. A thousand appologies :( I will close the question.